# Error in defining the object of DataSetIterator

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

I am trying to run the example of deeplearning4j LenetMnistExample. Error of "Frame is not available" occurrs in these lines

```
DataSetIterator mnistTrain = new MnistDataSetIterator(batchSize,true,12345);
DataSetIterator mnistTrain = new MnistDataSetIterator(batchSize,true,12345);
```

Can anyone help how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

But the example has something different. These lines:

```
    log.info("Load data....");
    DataSetIterator mnistTrain = new MnistDataSetIterator(batchSize,true,12345);
    DataSetIterator mnistTest = new MnistDataSetIterator(batchSize,false,12345);
```

Did you change them? Please join us on Gitter if you have questions:

https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j